# Моментальное отображение новых постов Wordpress на главной странице

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать моментальное отображение новых постов например на главной странице, движок WP.
Посетитель зашел ко мне на сайт, не перезагружая страницы он увидит новые посты, если в это время их кто нибудь добавит у меня на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходимо немного подправить HTML код вашей главной страницы.

1) WP хранит публикации в базе данных и дотянуться до них довольно просто, 1 SQL запрос и они уже у вас.

2) На главной странице напишите JS код который будет отправлять запрос на сервер и узнавать тем самым появилось чего или нет.

Итог: Для реализации вам нужен PHP скрипт для отправки запроса к БД. SQL для составления запроса. JS для отправки запроса на сервер от браузера.

Материалы по технологиям:

PHP-MySQLi: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php

JS-XHR: https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest

Успехов вам!

Comment: Владлен спасибо Вам за ответ, подскажите пожалуйста, возможно использовать как нибудь React или websocket для решения моего вопроса? Про JS код и php скрипт что Вы написали как я понимаю нужно будет ставить на крон все это дело.

Comment: Вам не нужен React или websocket, задача довольно простая и решается цепочкой из двух-трёх звеньев.
JS шлёт запрос к серверу, там PHP шлёт запрос к БД, БД отдаёт ответ PHP, PHP отдаёт JS, JS изменяет содержимое страницы, если есть новый пост.
И Крон здесь не нужен вообще. Вы же запросы из браузера шлёте, там для этих целей есть setInterval()

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на вопрос, как сделать ленту новостей как в соцсетях.
Это про Ajax.

Есть плагин WordPress Infinite Scroll – Ajax Load More
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Comment: Интересует как сделать отображение новых постов без перезагрузки пользователем страницы со скоростью до милесекунды, по сути нужен websocket или react. Посетитель зашел на мой сайт и ничего не делает, в этом время я добавляю пост в админке и ему моментально в эту же секунду отображается новый пост.

Comment: Вот такой же вопрос, смотрите в сторону Ajax https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0/ и даже тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993115/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-wordpress